# OpenSSL.NET create PFX

Tags: c#, openssl

I've been trying to figure this out for days.  I've given up.  I am trying to create a pfx from a CA's certificate and private key PEM files.  I was able to create the cert and key but now I can't figure out one last parameter in OpenSSL.X509.PKCS12.  Here's what I have:

```
    private void btnCreatePFX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string password = "p@ssw0rd";
        string key_path = @"certs\ca_key.key";
        string cert_path = @"certs\ca_cert.crt";
        string k = File.ReadAllText(key_path);
        string c = File.ReadAllText(cert_path);

        OpenSSL.Core.BIO key_bio = new OpenSSL.Core.BIO(k);
        OpenSSL.Core.BIO cert_bio = new OpenSSL.Core.BIO(c);

        OpenSSL.Crypto.CryptoKey key = OpenSSL.Crypto.CryptoKey.FromPrivateKey(k, "");
        OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate cert = new OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate(cert_bio);
        //OpenSSL.Core.Stack<OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate> hmm = new OpenSSL.Core.Stack<OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate>();

        var pfx = new OpenSSL.X509.PKCS12(password, key, cert, null); // <-- Problem with 4th parameter (I think)
    }
```

I know the 4th parameter needs to be OpenSSL.Core.Stack<OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate> but I can't figure out how to set it up.  The tests from the source code read a pfx then use the properties of that same pfx object to create the new one.  So, they easily get the accessor OpenSSL.X509.PKCS12.CACertificates which returns an OpenSSL.Core.Stack<OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate>.  Also, when simply reading a pfx I see that CACertificates is blank and has two members, Count and IsReadOnly.  When I try to create that object I'm not allowed to set Count and IsReadOnly because they're read-only.  Setting the 4th parameter to null and "" doesn't work either!  I'm stumped.

The examples are here: https://github.com/flaub/openssl-net/tree/master/test

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm an extreme noob when it comes to programming, so go easy on me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need a new instance of `OpenSSL.Core.Stack<OpenSSL.X509Certificate>`. In your example you already have one of these in the line:

`//OpenSSL.Core.Stack<OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate> hmm = new OpenSSL.Core.Stack<OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate>();`

So you should be able to create a PKCS12 instance by un-commenting that line and passing `hmm` as the 4th parameter as it is.

The `Stack<X509Certificate>` parameter is used to include multiple certificates (and keys) into a single file. You normally only include certificates that are part of the validation chain such as any intermediate or CA certificates for the certificate that you specified in the `X509Certificate cert` parameter.

The `CACertificates` property on the PKCS12 instance is the stack of certificates that have been added to the pfx file. The property is blank because there have been no certificates added to the stack. You can add additional certificates by using the `.Add(X509Certificate)` method on the `Stack<X509Certificate>` instance.

You will need to call `Dispose()` on the `Stack<X509Certificate>` instance (or wrap it in a `using(...)` block) before it goes out of scope.